# Symfony2 skips default_ttl setting in AppCache

Tags: symfony, caching

When I set TTLs explicitly in a controller

```
$response->setMaxAge(60);
$response->setSharedMaxAge(60);
```

everything works perfectly OK and I get the right response headers:

```
X-Symfony-Cache GET /hello/show/: miss, store
... and then ...
X-Symfony-Cache GET /hello/show/: stale, invalid, store
... and then ...
X-Symfony-Cache GET /hello/show/: fresh
```

But when I don't set TTLs explicitly in a controller and want to use default TTL settings:

```
class AppCache extends HttpCache {

    protected function getOptions() {
        return array(
            'debug' => true,
            'default_ttl' => 60,
            'private_headers' => array('Authorization', 'Cookie'),
            'allow_reload' => false,
            'allow_revalidate' => false,
            'stale_while_revalidate' => 2,
            'stale_if_error' => 60,
        );
    }
}
```

I always get a "miss".

```
X-Symfony-Cache GET /hello/show/: miss
```

It looks like Symfony doesn't take the default_ttl setting into account. Why?

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason. It's due to private/public reponses. The documentation states:

> Public vs private Responses¶
>
> Both gateway and proxy caches are considered "shared" caches as the
>   cached content is shared by more than one user. If a user-specific
>   response were ever mistakenly stored by a shared cache, it might be
>   returned later to any number of different users. Imagine if your
>   account information were cached and then returned to every subsequent
>   user who asked for their account page!
>
> To handle this situation, every response may be set to be public or
>   private:
>
> ```
> public: Indicates that the response may be cached by both private and shared caches;
> private: Indicates that all or part of the response message is intended for a single user and must not be cached by a shared cache.
> ```
>
> **Symfony conservatively defaults each response to be private. To take
>   advantage of shared caches (like the Symfony2 reverse proxy), the
>   response will need to be explicitly set as public**

So to make Symfony use the default_ttl setting you have to explicitly set your Response to be public like so:

```
$response->setPublic();
```